# Module code within different files

Tags: 7, forms

I wrote my own module that builds 4 forms with many features. Everything work great, but now i have reached 1000 lines of code and it's starting to get complicated to have all the forms on the same file.
I would like to make some .inc files, maybe one for each form (the biggest form has 9 functions related to it) to make more order to my code and make it easier to maintain it, but I have no clue on how to split the code in a way it will work.
How can i solve my issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split your code in as many files as you want. For every file except the *. module file add a line to your *.info file:

```
files[] = inc/my_form_1.inc
```

You can also place functionality into seperate files by specifying the path to the files in [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7). Have a lookt at the `file` property in the `hook_menu` description.